# Prove $f(x)$ has two distinct real roots. $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R $, $f(x) = x^2-8\ln x$.

Tags: calculus, functions

Prove $f(x)$ has two distinct real roots. $$f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R , f(x) = x^2-8\ln x$$
This is how I would usually go about solving this kind of exercises.
I calculate the derivative:

$$f'(x) = \frac{2(x-2)(x+2)}{x}, x\ne 0$$ 
Next I solve $f'(x)=0$.
$$ x_1=2, x_2=-2$$

Now because I determine the monotony intervals based on the sign of the derivative:

Then $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(0,2)$ and increasing on $(2,\infty)$.

Next I would determine the values at both ends of the interval(in this case the domain).

$$\lim_{x\to0}{(x^2-8\ln x)} = 0 - (-\infty) = \infty$$
I am stuck at the next limit, though.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{(x^2-8\ln x)}$$

I don't know how to solve this limit, I tried writing it as sum of products in hope it turns out to be either $\infty \cdot \infty$ or something similar I can apply L'hopsital to.

I know that it might seem pointless to write all this just for a limit, I could've asked for help with this limit instead, but it is all too often that I can't solve this kind of exercises using this method either because I can't calculate a limit or I can't solve $f'(x) = 0$ because in some cases it's a really complicated equation.

Is there another easier way to solve exercises of the form: Prove $f(x)$ has $n$ solutions in $(a,b)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=4-8ln(2)< 4-4 = 0$ therefore, since $f$ is continuous, by Bolzano's Theorem $f$ has a root in the interval $(1,2)$

$f(4)=16-8ln(4)>16-8\cdot2=0$ therefore $f$ has another root in the interval $(2,4)$

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using L'Hopital's theorem. There are usually simpler or more direct ways to calculate limits.

In this case, it's enough to realize that
$$
\log x < x
$$
for all $x > 0$. Thus
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 - 8\log x \geq \lim_{x \to \infty}x^2 - x = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{4} = \infty
$$